# How to append text dynamically after rect has been created

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

Dynamic code for rect value:

```
 g.append('g')
                  .selectAll('g')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('g')
                  .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + x0(d.State) + ',0)')
                  .selectAll('rect')
                  .data(d => keys.map(key => {return {key: key, value: d[key]}}))
                  .enter().append('rect')
                  .attr('x', d => x1(d.key))
                  .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
                  .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
                  .attr('height', d => innerHeight - y(d.value))
                  .attr('fill', d =>  z(d.key))
                  .append('text')
                  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
```

The result looks like:

```
 <g transform="translate(44,0)"><rect x="11" y="0" width="185" height="420" fill="#333333"></rect>
    <rect x="206" y="0" width="185" height="420" fill="#3490e9">
         <text>1</text>
    </rect>
    <rect x="401" y="420" width="185" height="0" fill="#ff5a00">
        <text>0</text>
    </rect>
    <rect x="596" y="420" width="185" height="0" fill="#9932CC">
        <text>0</text>
      </rect>
</g>
```

The expected result is:

```
 <g transform="translate(44,0)">
        <rect x="11" y="0" width="185" height="420" fill="#333333"></rect>
        <text>1</text>
        <rect x="206" y="0" width="185" height="420" fill="#3490e9"> 
         </rect>
        <text>1</text>
        <rect x="401" y="420" width="185" height="0" fill="#ff5a00"> 
        </rect>
        <text>1</text>
        <rect x="596" y="420" width="185" height="0" fill="#9932CC">
          </rect>
        <text>0</text>
    </g>
```

I need the `text` outside of every rect. Because the text value does not appear in the bar graph.

I've tried some attempt using afterinsert but got no luck

Also tried like

```
g.append('text')
 .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
```

but it only create 1 `text element` outside g

Anyway `g` is my `svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `text` elements nested in `rect` element because of D3's method chaining, where functions return the element being operated on (as long as the functions are being used to set a value). This means that when you have a chain functions looking like yours (simplified here):

```js
.append('g')
...
.selectAll('rect').data([data]).enter()
.append('rect')
...
.append('text')
```

Then you first append a `g`, then you append a `rect` element for each data point in your array, before lastly appending a `text` element to each `rect` element

There are a couple of ways of getting to where you want to be. That being said, you won't get the exact DOM representation, that you outline, but you can achieve the same effect.

The way I would recommend is to group your `rect` and `text` elements pairwise in a `g` element for each data point, as such:

```js
const outerG = g.append('g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + x0(d.State) + ',0)')

const pairG = outerG.selectAll('g')
    .data(d => keys.map(key => {return {key: key, value: d[key]}}))
    .enter().append('g')
    
pairG.append('rect')
    .attr('x', d => x1(d.key))
    .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
    .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', d => innerHeight - y(d.value))
    .attr('fill', d =>  z(d.key))
    
pairG.append('text')
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
```

This will first append a `g` element for each data point and store a reference to these `g` elements in `pairG`. Then we append a `rect` element and a `text` element individually to the `pairG` variable. This works because D3 makes the data points used for appending the previous `g` available for the `rect` and `text` elements. If we were to do a new `.selectAll('foo').data([data]).enter().append('foo')` sequence, this would not be the case as that would introduce new data points.

The code I have inserted should work with your data and setup, all though I cannot be sure as I do not have access to the data, scales, and variables you are using.

Comment: i accepted this answer even though it is adding an extra `g` thanks @matthias.rocks

Comment: One question @matthias.rocks do you have an idea to this `.attr('x', d => (x1(d.key) + x1.bandwidth())/2)`? bringing the value to the center of rect. the first rect value only centered but the others still remain from starting left side.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch In your code line, your `/2` is outside the function, meaning the return value of the function gets divided by 2. If you move it inside the function - `x1.bandwidth()/2` - I think you will get your desired result.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch Regarding the extra g, it is a common approach to nesting related elements. It has the benefit of making positioning of related elements easier because one can translate the `g` element, instead of positioning the pairwise elements individually, meaning one can generalize part of the positioning.